# CD-Drive don't work after installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, cd-drive

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS and now my CD-Drive is not working although I tried to test it with various CD and DVD's. How can I fix this problem?

This is the screenshot of Disks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is to install `udftools`. Open terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) and then type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install udftools
```

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work .